# Navigating Local Links with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm trying to create a side navbar using the template http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/ and so I saved it to my computer as an html file.
However, when I try to change the links in the side navbar any local links don't work. The top link is an original link, but the links below it I put in to point to html files in the same folder. How do I navigate to these files, and why is the website address displayed as a folder, and the significance of the # sign because I can't seem to find where that # sign file is. Thanks.

```
<DIV class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
<UL class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <LI class="active"><A 
  href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#">Overview </A></LI>

<ul>
<li><a href="i1.html">LOGCELL Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="i2.html">User Access Control</a></li>
<li><a href="i3.html">About Logcell</a></li>
</ul>
<li>Cognos</li>
<ul>
<li><a href="c1.html">Cognos Capabilities</a></li>
<li><a href="c2.html">Cognos Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="c3.html">The Congnos User Interface</a></li>
</ul>

</UL></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend some time reading about how to use links and anchors. Maybe this article might help http://html.com/anchors-links/ (just google for more/other).

The '#' sign is used to link to anchors inside the page. If there is nothing after the '#' the link won't have any effect. For example, this link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#carousel-example-generic will focus on the id element that has the 'carousel-example-generic' name. If you don't put the name, it links to the whole page. So maybe the above example explains the '#' sign.

If you want to navigate to local files you need to decide if you want absolute or relative URLs. For relative paths, you can use '.' or '..' with the name of the file you want.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I'm still not sure why the links don't work though, when I have the exact same links in another page they work, just for some reason in this context they don't work